# Error in SimpleImputer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My code:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

fill_values=SimpleImputer(missing_values=0,strategy='mean')

X_train=fill_values.fit(X_train)
X_test=fill_values.fit(X_test)

imp_X_train=fill_values.transform(X_train)
imp_X_test=fill_values.trainsform(X_test)
```

Gives the error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SimpleImputer'
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform a data array, for example, `X_train`, with a preprocessor like `SimpleImputer` you should use method `.fit_transform`.

For example: `X_train = fill_values.fit_transform(X_train)`

If you use only `fit` it will return an instance of type `SimpleImputer` which is your error.

Comment: Additionally, _do not_ use `fit_transform` on the test data.  See @Zvi's [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/89033/55122).

Answer (score 1):

The output of a `fit()` method of a transformer is the class instance itself (it returns 'self'). Thus by doing:

```
X_train=fill_values.fit(X_train)
```

you destroyed the `X_train` dataFrame, and thus when you use it as input to transform() you get an error. Also, when calling `fit()` it prepares for the `transform()` so you should not call it again with other data, before calling `transform()`.

You should instead do:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

fill_values=SimpleImputer(missing_values=0,strategy='mean')

fill_values.fit(X_train)
imp_X_train=fill_values.transform(X_train)

fill_values.fit(X_test)
imp_X_test=fill_values.trainsform(X_test)
```